# DBFit - Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4]

Tags: dbfit

My script:

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h

!path lib/*.jar

|import |
|dbfit.SqlServerTest|

!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|

!|Connect|SUKHI-PC\SQLEXPRESS|SUKHI-PC\XXX|XXX|XXX|
```

Masked a few details but the error message is:

Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4].

Don't understand. From what I've read online it may be that my Path is not correct but no idea what it's looking for as Connect is a command not fixture. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old post, but for future reference purposes; "Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4]" error is thrown by fitnesse when I was trying to connect to a sql server in a dbfit test using slim server without calling DatabaseEnvironment constructor. you can overcome this error by planning your dbfit test something like below..

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}

|Import       |
|dbfit.fixture|
|dbfit.SqlServerTest|

!|DatabaseEnvironment|sqlserver                                      |
|Connect             |11.11.11.11:8888|username|password|databasename|
```