# db-fit- Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4]

Tags: oracle, fitnesse, dbfit

Here is my code:

```
!***< Hidden

!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
!path   C:\Users\c008854\workspace\MQValidator\build\libs\*.jar
!path   C:\Progra~1\dbfit-complete-3.2.0\lib\*
|import     |
|com.connect|
*!


|Divisionp                      |
|numerator|denominator|quotient?|
|10       |2          |6.0      |
|12.6     |3          |4.2      |
|22       |7          |~=3.14   |
|9        |3          |<5       |
|11       |2          |4<_<6    |
|100      |4          |33       |

!|dbfit.OracleTest|


!|Connect|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:1522|xxxuser|xxxpass|xxxname|
```

However I get the following error

```
Connect Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4]
```

I looked at the following, but it didn't solve my problem.

[DBFit - Could not invoke constructor for Connect[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920046/dbfit-could-not-invoke-constructor-for-connect4)

Instead I got another error saying:

```
Connect Could not invoke constructor for DatabaseEnvironment
```

What is the reason for the error that is in the title?

Answer (score 0):

It means the `Connect` initialisation (constructor) failed, either due to invalid credentials or other problems.
You should look at the Java logs to see what was the exact reason.

Comment: i specified the -v option when running the fitnesse jar, no error logs are displayed

Comment: it's not Fitnesse throwing the error but the fixture that's throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

Put the line `!|dbfit.OracleTest|` as the first line on the page.  This lets the DB Fit fixture control the entire page, and recognize commands like `!|Connect|...`

Comment: I placed it on first line(before !***<Hidden) and the error still persists.

Comment: Then I'm not sure whats happening.  Hopefully one of the DbFit maintainers will see this...